# drawing great circle arc with Basemap knowing starting point and a bearing

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to draw a great circle arc on maps.

The function `drawgreatcircle()` in Basemap is usefull as long as you know the latitude and longitude of the starting and the destination points on the map.

My problem is that I have the starting point and a bearing in degrees referenced to the North pole.

Applications : Radio Direction Finding by triangulation.

Comment: I think there's no equivalent function for your needs. You could however, derive the lon/lat-values of the end point mathematically (knowing the northpole-referenced bearing) and assign these to the drawgreatcircle()-function.

Comment: @ala Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you say [`drawgreatcircle`](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawgreatcircle) needs two points, you have the first point and you need to compute the second point. In order to compute the second point you say you have the bearing but I think you need also a distance along the bearing, otherwise how much the great circle will be long?

With a starting point, a bearing and a distance along the bearing you can compute the destination point with a calculator like [Great Circle Calculator](http://williams.best.vwh.net/gccalc.htm) by Ed Williams using the calculator labeled **"Compute lat/lon given radial and distance from a known point"**.

Note that, to solve your problem, there is some python code by Thomas Lecocq (based on the Ed Williams one) at the page [Matplotlib Basemap tutorial 08: Shooting Great Circles](http://www.geophysique.be/2011/02/19/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-08-shooting-great-circles/).

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no equivalent function for your needs. You could however, derive the lon/lat-values of the end point mathematically (knowing the northpole-referenced bearing) and assign these to the `drawgreatcircle()`- function.